# It seems my code is making an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm a python learner and It seems my code is making an infinite loop in the *while* expression, but I don't understand why.

What I want is a program to sum the first five odd numbers in this list.

This is a very basic exercise in Udacity site, the output was *program shut down for using 13 CPU seconds* and in the Windows python3 it doesn't show any output. After some tests, my suspicion is a problem with an infinite loop in the *while* expression.

```
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]

    z=0
    s=0
    for i in range(len(num_list)):
        while z<=5:
            if num_list[i]%2==1:
                z+=1
                s+=num_list[i]
    print(s)
```

Comment: 422 is even, when would `z` get updated then?

Comment: Go through this with pen and paper to understand what you're trying to do…

Comment: Consider using ``if`` instead of ``while`` – you only want to run the innermost part *once* per ``i``. Also consider to ``break`` the ``for`` loop when you have found enough off numbers. An alternative is to ``filter`` the list for odd numbers and take only the first five, *then* sum these up.

Comment: @Austin the sum of the odd numbers is ok, I tested without the while expression. The problem is when I try to add up just the first five numbers.

Comment: If you want this to operate only on the first 5 numbers, use `num_list[:5]`.

Comment: @Austin I got it!

Comment: @deceze the first five odd numbers, not the five numbers in the list

Comment: FWIW, the pythonic solution to this is something along the lines of `sum(itertools.islice((i for i in num_list if i % 2 == 1), 5))`. Even if this may be slightly advanced for you at this stage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow your code

- you start index `0`
- read value is `422`
- you don't go into the if
- you don't increase `z`
- you stays in the while loop for infinite

```
for i in range(len(num_list)):
    while z <= 5:
        if num_list[i] % 2 == 1:
```

---

**Solution 1**:  don't use 2 loops (while and for) because you want to do 2 things : iterate iver the values **and** check the 5 conditions. You may just use a `break` when you got five

```
for i in range(len(num_list)):
    if num_list[i] % 2 == 1:
        z += 1
        s += num_list[i]
    if z >= 5:
        break
```

**Solution 2**:  use a different logic

- get the odd ones
- get the first 5 of them
- sum them

```
r = sum(list(filter(lambda i: i % 2 == 1, num_list))[:5])
```

Answer (score 3):

your for loop will put the first item of `num_list` into `i` so `i` will be `422`. you then have a while loop that will run for as long as `z<=5`.

You then check if `422 % 2` is equal to 1. Its not 422 mod 2 is 0. So since this condition is not true, you never update z so z will always remain as 0. And since 0 is less than 5 your loop will run forever

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `if num_list[i]%2==1:` does not trigger. This prevents both the `for` and `while` loop conditions from changing, trapping the execution in the inner loop.

The first change to avoid an infinite loop is avoiding the loop itself. Since the count of odd numbers should be checked only once per number, use `if` instead of `while`.

```
z=0
s=0
for i in range(len(num_list)):
    if z<=5:  # checked only once for each i
        if num_list[i]%2==1:
            z+=1
            s+=num_list[i]
print(s)
```

This will already fix your problem. You may want to clean up your code further, though. Writing idiomatic code will naturally avoid certain pitfalls, such as infinite loops.

First, consider that the two checks have separate purpose. The `z` check exists to *halt* iteration, the `%2` check to *select* elements. Halting iteration is done using `break`.

```
z=0
s=0
for i in range(len(num_list)):
    if z<=5:  # break condition
        break
    if num_list[i]%2==1:  # sum condition
        z+=1
        s+=num_list[i]
print(s)
```

Now, keep in mind that Python's container types are iterable by themselves. There is no need for a separate `i` index, numbers can be fetched directly from the list. Also, keep in mind that non-zero numbers are considered "true" – instead of `num % 2 == 1`, check only for `num %2`.

```
z=0
s=0
for number in num_list:  # iterate on elements, eliminate i
    if z <= 5:
        break
    if number % 2:  # only test that it is not zero
        z += 1
        s += number
print(s)
```

Python has several tools to simplify working with iterables. A generator expression allows to cheaply filter and transform an iterable. This allows to remove all even numbers before the `for` loop.

```
z=0
s=0
# only work on odd numbers
for odd_number in (num for num in num_list if num % 2):
    if z <= 5:
        break
    z += 1
    s += odd_number
print(s)
```

Since increasing an iteration count is so common, Python has a builtin to do that for you: `enumerate`. It takes an iterable, and counts up as new items are fetched.

```
s=0
# automatically calculate z
for z, odd_number in enumerate(num for num in num_list if num % 2):
    if z == 5:
        break
    s += odd_number
print(s)
```

In this case, the only purpose of `z` is to select the first 5 elements. Whenever you need to work with "the first n" or "the last m" items, consider to use slicing. Slicing is used on containers using `container[start:stop:step]` syntax, or on arbitrary iterables using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

```
from itertools import islice

s=0
# only use the first 5 odd numbers                             V
for odd_number in islice((num for num in num_list if num % 2), 5):
    s += odd_number
print(s)
```

Finally, summing up an iterable is also a very common task, and Python has a builtin for that as well: `sum`. Since by now the entire logic has been shifted from the loop to the iterable, it can be summed up in one go.

```
s = sum(islice((num for num in num_list if num % 2), 5))
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]
c = 0
sum_ = 0
for number in num_list:
    if (c > 4 ):
        break
    if (number % 2 == 1):
        sum_ += number
        c+=1
print(sum_)
```

prints

```
993
```